# Show values in a nested loop horizontally in a table

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, for-loop, foreach

I have two array.

TempData["item_list"] like this => `["car1","car2","car3"]`

Model like this => `[{"item1","item3","item5"}, {"item2","item4"}, {"item4","item5"}]`

```
    <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                @foreach (var car in TempData["item_list"] as IEnumerable<string>)
                {
                    <th>@car</th>
                }

                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    @foreach (var itemm in item)
                    {

                        <td>@itemm</td>
                    }
                }
            </tr>
    </table>
```

That's how I want to show it in the table.
[image]

My View

[image]

Comment: Please post code not screen shots.  Also looks like you have code, what do the results look like for what you have?  What is not working?

Comment: @Brad  I updated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pseudocode for what you want -

```
var carArray = ["car1","car2","car3"];
var itemsArray = [{"item1","item3","item5"}, {"item2","item4"}, {"item4","item5"}];

for(int i = 0, i < carArray.Count, i ++)
{
   <tr>
      <td>
          <strong>@carArray[i]</strong>
      </td>

      @foreach(var item in itemsArray[i])
      {
          <td>itemArray[i]</td>              
      }
   </tr>
}
```

Each car is on a new row.  Then loop through the items in the `itemArray` at the same index as the car and put it on the same row.  This doesn't contain any validation to verify the `itemsArray` length is the same as `carArray`, of course.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the code a bit. I removed the "i" in foreach and it worked correctly.